# Laravel + add element to cookie and do not include in query

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, cookies

I'm trying to do the following:

**At page load:**

Select **one** random idea from database.

My code:

```
public function index()
{
    if(Cookie::get('ideas'))
    {
        $ideas = Cookie::get('ideas');
        $ideas = unserialize($ideas);
    }
    else
    {
        $ideas = array();
    }

    $random_idea = Idea::inRandomOrder()->first();
    $ideas[] = $random_idea->id;

    Cookie::queue('ideas', serialize($ideas));

    return view('app', compact('random_idea'));
}
```

I'm checking if the cookie is already set, if set, add the random idea to the cookie. If not, create new array and add the id to the array.

**When they click a button on page (through ajax call).**

My code:

```
public function idea(Request $request)
{
    $ideas = Cookie::get('ideas');
    $ideas = unserialize($ideas);

    $random_idea = Idea::inRandomOrder()->first();
    $ideas[] = $random_idea->id;

    Cookie::queue('ideas', serialize($ideas));

    return response()->json($random_idea);
}
```

I have 2 problems:

- The cookie variable is an array with always one element (id isn't added to the array)
- How can I select one random element from database that's **NOT** in the array?

Comment: You really should isolate questions to one problem, but with your first problem, did you try dumping `$ideas` after you unserialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of ids, Laravel's query builder accepts an array with whereNotIn.  This will run the SQL `WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, etc)`:

```
$random_idea = Idea::whereNotIn('id', $ideas)->inRandomOrder()->first();
```